# ImageButton touch event still called after dragging finger away

Tags: android, button, libgdx, imagebutton

I have an ImageButton in my LibGDX game with a minor bug that might annoy the user. If I pressed on the button, but decided not to want to click it, I would drag my finger away.
However even if my finger is no longer on top of the ImageButton after dragging it away, the `touchUp()` method is still called.

How can I stop the touchUp event from happening?

I don't know if somehow getting the bounds of that ImageButton (how would that go), and seeing if the touchUp location corresponds, might work. I've tried looking it up, but I haven't been able to find anything so far because my issue is very specific.

This is how I've initialized my button:

```
retryButton = new ImageButton(getDrawable(new Texture("RetryButtonUp.jpg")), getDrawable(new Texture("RetryButtonDown.jpg")));


retryButton.addListener(new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            if(touchable) {
                game.setScreen(new PlayScreen(game, difficulty));
                dispose();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `ClickListener` instead of an `InputListener`, and instead of overriding the `touchUp` method, override the `clicked` method.

Comment: Thanks... do you have any idea why my question got downvotes?

Comment: Button already has a ClickListener built in--it makes more sense to add a ChangeListener rather than another ClickListener to avoid redundant input processing. No idea why your question was downvoted--looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Extending off of grimrader22's answer, I would also recommend using a ClickListener for handling touch events, but you'll still get the same issue of firing off the code in the `touchUp` event even if you drag your finger outside of the ImageButton, which is why the `clicked` method should work just fine.

But, if you want to use the `touchUp` and `touchDown` methods, here ya go: The x and y values in `touchUp` and `touchDown` represent the local coordinates of the touch event on the ImageButton. So, the simple solution is to make sure the the x and y of the event within the `touchUp` method are both within the ImageButton's local coordinates...

```
    @Override
    public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        boolean inX = x >= 0 && x < getWidth();
        boolean inY = y >= 0 && y < getHeight();
        if(inX && inY && touchable) {
            game.setScreen(new PlayScreen(game, difficulty));
            dispose();
        }
    }
```